# Threading the needle: finding the name of the actual argument corresponding to a formal of an outer function

Tags: r, metaprogramming, pipeline, tidyverse, variable-names

The function `strip()` below tries to produce a brief report on the result of its operation via the tee pipe (`%T>%`). Because this function is in turn being handed to a wrapper function and then to `purrr::pwalk`, which will supply it with a bunch of dataframes one by one, I want to get a report of its operation on each dataframe along with the dataframe name; which is to say, the name of the actual dataframe that is supplied to correspond to the formal argument `tib` in the function below.  In the example supplied, this would be `"tst_df"`. I don't know the names in advance of running the function, as they are constructed from the filenames read from disk and various other inputs.

Somewhat to my surprise, I actually have almost all of this working, except for getting the name of the supplied dataframe. In the example below, the code that is supposed to do this is `enexpr(XX)`, but I have also tried `expr(XX)`, and both of these expressions applied to `tib` or the dot (`.`), with or without a preceding `!!`. Also `deparse(substitute())` on `XX`, `tib`, and `.`, but without the bang bangs.

I see that the names is stripped initially by pass-by-value, and then again, maybe, by each stage of the pipe, including the `T`, and again, maybe, by (`XX = .`) in the anonymous function after the `T`. But I know R + tidyverse will have a way. I just hope it does not involve providing an integer to count backwards up the call stack

```
tst_df <- tibble(A = 1:10, B = 11:20, C=21:30, D = 31:40)
tst_df    
################################################################################
# The strip function expects a non-anonymous dataframe, from which it removes
# the rows specified in remove_rows and the columns specified in remove_cols. It
# also prints a brief report; just the df name, length and width.
strip <- function(tib, remove_rows = FALSE, remove_cols = NULL){
  remove_rows <- enquo(remove_rows)
  remove_cols <- enquo(remove_cols)
  out <- tib %>%
    filter(! (!! remove_rows))  %>%
    select(- !! remove_cols) %T>% (function(XX = .){
      function(XX = .)print(
          paste0("length of ", enxpr(XX), " = ", nrow(XX), " Width = ", ncol(XX)))
          cat("\n")
        })
  out  
}

out_tb <- strip(tib = tst_df, remove_rows = (A < 3 | D > 38),  remove_cols = c(C, D))
out_tb
```

Comment: Please use inline code formatting, it's hard to read otherwise. This time I've helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the name of `tib` at the beginning of your function,
it will be found by your reporter function:

```
strip <- function(tib, remove_rows = FALSE, remove_cols = NULL) {
  remove_rows <- enquo(remove_rows)
  remove_cols <- enquo(remove_cols)
  tib_name <- as.character(substitute(tib))
  report <- function(out) {
    cat("output length of", tib_name, "=", nrow(out), ", width =", ncol(out), "\n")
  }

  tib %>%
    filter(! (!! remove_rows))  %>%
    select(- !! remove_cols) %T>%
    report
}

out_tb <- strip(tib = tst_df, remove_rows = (A < 3 | D > 38),  remove_cols = c(C, D))
output length of tst_df = 6 , width = 2
```

Comment: <strikes forehead with palm> Thanks Alexis! Just what I needed.